# How to dynamically change point colors in scatter3d animation with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to draw the animation of several 3DScatter with matplotlib. I succeeded to draw all the points but I'm struggling with the colors. Even if I'm calling the function `set_color(..)` nothing is changed.
Here is what I'm currently doing, `to_plot` is an array of size `total` with `(5120, 3)` float elements and `colors` is an array of size `total` with `(5120,)` elements (equal to 'r' or 'b'):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

total = 10

num_whatever = 100    # old = 5120

to_plot = [np.random.rand(num_whatever, 3) for i in range(total)]
colors = [['r' if i%2==0 else 'b' for i in range(num_whatever)] for i in range(total)]
red_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='red', label='Men')
blue_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='blue', label='Women')

fig = plt.figure()
ax3d = Axes3D(fig)
scat3D = ax3d.scatter([],[],[], s=10)
ttl = ax3d.text2D(0.05, 0.95, "", transform=ax3d.transAxes)

def update_plot(i):
    print i, to_plot[i].shape
    ttl.set_text('PCA on 3 components at step = {}'.format(i*20))
    scat3D._offsets3d = np.transpose(to_plot[i])
    scat3D.set_color(colors[i])
    return scat3D,

def init():
    scat3D.set_offsets([[],[],[]])
    ax3d.set_xlim(-1.,2.)
    ax3d.set_ylim(-0.5,0.7)
    ax3d.set_zlim(-1.,0.75)
    plt.style.use('ggplot')
    plt.legend(handles=[red_patch, blue_patch])

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_plot, init_func=init, blit=False, interval=100, frames=xrange(total))

# ani.save(os.path.join(config.workdir, 'gif', 'bins','anim.gif'), writer="imagemagick")

plt.plot()
```

Comment: please post a mvce (add the imports needed)

Comment: Sorry, done ;) ! For to_plot and colors I'm actually reading numpy array saved on my computer.

Comment: `to_plot` is not defined

Comment: I added a random example

Answer (score 3):

The scatter plot is a `Path3DCollection`. It can have a colormap associated to it such that its points are colored according to the color array.

So you can provide a list of numeric values to the scatter via `scat3D.set_array(colors[i])`, where `colors[i] = [0,1,0,...,1,0,1]`. Those values are then mapped according to the colormap in use. For blue/red color this is simple, because there exists already a colormap `"bwr"` from blue to red.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

total = 10

num_whatever = 100

to_plot = [np.random.rand(num_whatever, 3) for i in range(total)]
colors = [np.tile([0,1],num_whatever//2) for i in range(total)]
red_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='red', label='Men')
blue_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='blue', label='Women')

fig = plt.figure()
ax3d = Axes3D(fig)
scat3D = ax3d.scatter([],[],[], s=10, cmap="bwr", vmin=0, vmax=1)
scat3D.set_cmap("bwr") # cmap argument above is ignored, so set it manually
ttl = ax3d.text2D(0.05, 0.95, "", transform=ax3d.transAxes)

def update_plot(i):
    print i, to_plot[i].shape
    ttl.set_text('PCA on 3 components at step = {}'.format(i*20))
    scat3D._offsets3d = np.transpose(to_plot[i])
    scat3D.set_array(colors[i])
    return scat3D,

def init():
    scat3D.set_offsets([[],[],[]])
    plt.style.use('ggplot')
    plt.legend(handles=[red_patch, blue_patch])

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_plot, init_func=init, 
                              blit=False, interval=100, frames=xrange(total))

ani.save("ani.gif", writer="imagemagick")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much ! I just tried and it's working for the `plt.show()` but the saved GIF does not have the colors changed, is it the same for you ? (I just copied and pasted your code on my computer)

Comment: The saved gif is what you see embeded in the answer above. So yes, this is working fine for me.

Comment: I see... Which version of Python and matplotlib did you use?

Comment: Python 2.7, matplotlib 2.1. I would however guess that the code should work with any matplotlib version >=1.5.

Comment: Then I don't see why it's not working on my computer :/

Comment: Well, if it's working when shown on screen, it does not seem to be a problem with the code itself, right? So I guess it will require a bit of debugging from your side: Try to find a minimal example which works and one which does not work as expected, look at the differences and if you're stuck ask a question specifically about saving as gif. Try a 2D plot, try a plot without scatter etc.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why calling `set_color` failed is described here: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/13035

> ... the bug is due to the `set_facecolor` not setting `_facecolor3d` because it is inherited from the base class (`Collection`) setting `_facecolors`. The same for edge colors.

And yes, this is a bug in `matplotlib`.

Therefore, if you want to change the face colors, direct assignment of `_facecolor3d` just work out fine. Note that you must assign it with an rgba_array, like

```
scat3D._facecolor3d[0] = [1., 0., 0., 1.]
```

or instead, if you want to use the presets (like 'r', '.5', etc.), you can do it this way

```
scat3D.set_color(...)
scat3D._facecolor3d = scat3D.get_facecolor()
scat3D._edgecolor3d = scat3D.get_edgecolor()
```

I have tested on both python 2.7 and 3.6, and no problem arose.